# Load encrypted image or files from URL (Firestore)

Tags: android-studio

I just recently using android studio about 3 weeks and made 1 app, but i got problem when trying to load an image which was encrypted before uploading it to Firestore.
I'm using Picasso to load image from URL, but i don't know how to load an encrypted one from URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, If found my own way to solve this.
All I needed to do is to just download the file from firestore and save it (with 2 ways - "download as byte" or "downlaod to cache dir").